# Gmail rejecting mail with attachment?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, postfix-mta

Good afternoon, I'm having a big trouble because my mail server sends emails to everyone but Gmail - emails with attachments, the ones without attachments are received properly.
For instance I send a PDF ticket to testing@gmail.com and BCC to othermail@sapo.pt. The BCC is received properly but the gmail seems to be ignored.
What is the logic in this? Is it somekind of ipv6 configuration?
Here is my latest logs:

```
Nov 20 13:21:20 Server postfix/smtpd[13857]: 5B97B8AA1C0: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 20 13:21:20 Server postfix/cleanup[13865]: 5B97B8AA1C0: message-id=<1384960878.528cd36ee84b0@www.server.com.br>
Nov 20 13:21:20 Server postfix/qmgr[13004]: 5B97B8AA1C0: from=<info@server.com.br>, size=22628, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 20 13:21:20 Server postfix/smtpd[13857]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 20 13:21:21 Server postfix/smtp[13866]: 2FA958AA103: to=<testing@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.27]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.18/0/0.42/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1384960885 hb10si8733755qeb.46 - gsmtp)
Nov 20 13:21:21 Server postfix/qmgr[13004]: 2FA958AA103: removed
```

As far as I see it, the status is sent but it doesn't arrive to the account... Thank you!

---

Edit: Once in a while I get this strange log entries that I don't have a clue what it is:

```
Nov 20 13:50:03 Server postfix/smtpd[14010]: connect from 50-202-171-113-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[50.202.171.113]
Nov 20 13:50:06 Server postfix/smtpd[14010]: warning: 50-202-171-113-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[50.202.171.113]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: (strange-password-here)
Nov 20 13:50:06 Server postfix/smtpd[14010]: lost connection after AUTH from 50-202-171-113-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[50.202.171.113]
Nov 20 13:50:06 Server postfix/smtpd[14010]: disconnect from 50-202-171-113-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[50.202.171.113]
Nov 20 13:53:26 Server postfix/anvil[14013]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:50.202.171.113) at Nov 20 13:50:03
Nov 20 13:53:26 Server postfix/anvil[14013]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:50.202.171.113) at Nov 20 13:50:03
Nov 20 13:53:26 Server postfix/anvil[14013]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov 20 13:50:03
```

Comment: There is no IPv6 information in that log snippet, just IPv4. Most likely the email's being detected as spam. Check the account's spam folder.

Comment: yes, you are correct. The emails with pdf attached are marked as spam. the other ones are getting through the inbox folder.